# Scatter plot derived from two pandas dataframes with multiple columns in plotly [express]

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plotly, plotly-express

I want to create a scatter plot that drives its `x` values from one dataframe and `y` values from another dataframe having multiple columns.

`x_df` :

```
   red  blue
0  1    2
1  2    3
2  3    4
```

`y_df`:

```
   red  blue
0  1    2
1  2    3
2  3    4
```

I want to plot a scatter plot like [image]

I would like to have two `red` and `blue` traces such that `x` values should come from `x_df` and `y` values are derived from `y_df`.

Comment: you need to have a uniform data set - IMHO simplest way is to merge / join data frames .  Is the index the join key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- at some layer you need to do data integration.  IMHO better to be done at *data layer* i.e. *pandas*
- have modified your sample data so two traces do not overlap
- used `join()` assuming that index of data frames is the join key
- could have further structured dataframe,  however I generated multiple traces using **plotly express** modifying as required to ensure colors and legends are created
- have not considered axis labels...

```
x_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""   red  blue
0  1    2
1  2    3
2  3    4"""), sep="\s+")

y_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""   red  blue
0  1.1    2.2
1  2.1    3.2
2  3.1    4.2"""), sep="\s+")

df = x_df.join(y_df, lsuffix="_x", rsuffix="_y")

px.scatter(df, x="red_x", y="red_y").update_traces(
    marker={"color": "red"}, name="red", showlegend=True
).add_traces(
    px.scatter(df, x="blue_x", y="blue_y")
    .update_traces(marker={"color": "blue"}, name="blue", showlegend=True)
    .data
)
```

[image]